Excel XIRR: first value is small or zero returns odd value
I'm trying to calculate the XIRR of a large (>200) number of investments, each of which has a set of values associated with dates.  For some of the investments, the first date in the table is the date of the investment, so the row contains a negative value in the first column.  For others, the investment comes later, so the first column is zero.

I have linked to a screenshot but in case that doesn't work:
Dates          1 Mar 2022      2 Mar 2022      1 Mar 2024      XIRR

Investment A   -100,000        0               120,000         9.53%

Investment B   0               -100,000        120,000         0.00%

The XIRR for Investment A comes out right - a 20% increase over two years is 9.53% pa.
The XIRR for Investment B is calculated at zero - which is obviously wrong.  It should be almost exactly the same (9.53%), because the initial investment is only made a day later.
But XIRR is confused by the fact that the first number is zero.
I can get around this by making the first number a small negative number, for example -0.01.  XIRR then calculates correctly for investment B.  But that doesn't work in my real-life example, where there are about 200 columns with different dates, most of them blank for each investment: in that case, having a small negative number in the first column gives the same result as having zero - XIRR miscalculates.
I hope I've explained this clearly.  Any suggestions would be very welcome!
Thank you -- David

You would need to construct a formula to start the array from the first non-zero value. I would start with INDEX(MATCH()) to get the start of the array that workes with XIRR, how you get the rest of the array depends on what version of excel you have. You could probably search here to find what you need.

That first value representing the date of the investment needs to be negative. So one way is, assuming no version constraints, try:
E2: =LET(
    dts, $B$1:$D$1,
    vals, B2:D2,
    first_Col, XMATCH(TRUE, vals < 0),
    XIRR(DROP(vals, , first_Col - 1), DROP(dts, , first_Col - 1))
)

and fill down
Or as a formula entered into a single cell that will spill down:
=LET(
    dts, $B$1:$D$1,
    vals, B2:D3,
    BYROW(
        vals,
        LAMBDA(arr,
            LET(
                first_Col, XMATCH(TRUE, arr < 0) - 1,
                XIRR(DROP(arr, , first_Col), DROP(dts, , first_Col))
            )
        )
    )
)



That's brilliant - thanks very much.  And I'd never heard of the LET function before, so that's a great discovery.
